# Unauthorized status when accessing /oauth/token_key

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am building an Oauth Server using Spring with this [tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server).

During the Resource Server implementation I noticed that the token key endpoint (/oauth/token_key) was not public.

Based on [this doc](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html#resource-server-configuration) I tried to add the following to the AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
```

and also:

```
security.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')")
               .checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
```

Both configurations did not worked. I also tried to add a rule on my WebSecurityAdapter:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token_key").permitAll();
}
```

Now I will se a dialog asking for login and password and when I click cancel I will receive the following:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Unauthorized
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: You need to authenticate to see a shared key
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenKeyEndpoint.getKey(TokenKeyEndpoint.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    (...)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation I found the problem: I forgot to inject the keyPair into the tokenConverter used to convert to JWT and add some extra user info:

```
//Inside AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter

@Autowired
private MyJwtTokenEnhancer jwtTokenEnhancer;
@Autowired
private KeystoreService keystoreService;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        //this line solved the issue
        jwtTokenEnhancer.setKeyPair(keystoreService.getKeyPair());

        endpoints.authenticationManager(manager)
            .accessTokenConverter(jwtTokenEnhancer)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .addInterceptor(new AuditInterceptor());
}
```

Comment: Can please help on this, same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65173600/spring-security-oauth-oauth-token-key-returns-404-error-not-found